# Tools for statistical analysis of binary streams

Tags: binary-analysis, tools

I'm in the process of decoding the semantics of an unknown binary stream<sup>1</sup>. I've come to a point where I understand the overall structure: A `tag` byte, followed by a size field, and a blob of bytes of that size, e.g. `80 02 42 0a` (type: 0x80, size: 2 bytes, data: 66, 10).

To help me drill deeper I'm looking for a tool that allows me to extract the individual chunks of data, run queries against those, and arbitrarily transform the results. I'm looking for simple queries (like *"all packets with a specific tag"*), but also need more complex filters (e.g. *"distribution of all size values for packets with a specific tag"*).

Are there any tools that allow me to easily perform those queries, given the following requirement?

- Needs to understand the overall stream structure.
- Needs to have basic decoding capabilities (e.g. to extract base128-encoded `varint`s as used by [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)).
- Needs customizable filters (e.g. by tag, size, or data).
- [Optional] Ability to control display of data, like 64-bit [FILETIME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) values.
- [Optional] Ability to render graphs.
- Needs to run on Windows (preferably free).

---

<sup>1</sup> *The data is streamed off of an embedded device. I have access to fully self-contained chunks of that data as binary files.*

Comment: You might be able to use WireShark if you write a custom dissector. Kaitai Struct might be helpful as well. Here's a basic script that allows converting from a Kaitai Struct to a Wireshark LUA dissector: https://github.com/joushx/kaitai-to-wireshark

Comment: @dvd: *"Stream"* was possibly a misleading term. I do have fully self-contained chunks of the stream available as files, so I'm not looking to analyze network traffic. I also played with Kaitai Struct today. It's a great tool, but it will only become useful to me, once I know the meaning of the data. I'm not there yet. Right now I'm looking at `tag` `size` `<blob of data>`. I don't understand `<blob of data>` yet, and I need help with that. To get there, I need to test hypotheses, by collecting statistical data.

Comment: WireShark isn't limited to network traffic, it can dissect any data given the correct dissector (try using it to open a PNG file for example). However, if all else fails and you can't find a better tool or strategy, it might be useful to think of your data as a network stream nonetheless. Write a simple script to combine all of the different binary files to a pcap file, where the data of each packet is the contents of a single binary file. Then, create a basic dissector that is able to dissect "tag, size, blob". You can then use WireShark's/tshark's filtering capabilities for analysis/stats.

Comment: @dvd: I got it eventually to work, writing a tool to convert the binary stream into a pcap file, and jotting up a Lua dissector. While helpful in finding patterns I wasn't even looking for, Wireshark ultimately turned out not to be suitable for the task. It really is meant for communication protocols, and that's really where it shines. I went on to write up a custom tool that does what I need. The advice was still helpful.

Comment: Impressive! Glad to hear you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: Glad you got the specific issue solved -- for others with similar needs, you might be interested in Veles (https://codisec.com/veles/) which is built for more manual binary slicing/dicing as opposed to Katai's more API-focused approach.